# JQuery - Is() function optimalization

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, function

I have many iterations where I want to check if myObject have .example class.
I can do this with templateObject that is predefined during initialization as $('.class'):

```
if(myObject.Is( templateObject )
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Alternatively, I can use class name directly:

```
if(myObject.Is( '.example' )
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

So I want to know if second example makes jQuery search through DOM in every iteration or comparison is made in more optimal way? Which example is better?

Comment: Use `if(myObject.hasClass( 'example' )` instead.

Comment: It's basically equivalent to the standard `.matches()`  method which simply applies the selector to the current element and returns `true` if the selector matches... `someElement.matches(".example")`

Comment: @squint Do you talking about javascript? As far as I know there is no such method.

Comment: @Mohammad: Yes, JavaScript. It's a standard DOM Element method. `document.body.matches("body") // true`

Comment: @Mohammad: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches

Comment: no...it does not perform a dom search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO jquery `hasClass()` is more efficient here, it is made specifically for this purpose.

```
if (myObject.hasClass('example')){
    // Code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your two examples are not the same. If you call `$('.example')` you will find all elements that have the class `.example`, if you use this as a test for `myObject.is(templateObject)` then you will test if one of the elements in the jQuery result set `myObject` equals to one of the elements in the result set `templateObject`. So if the DOMElements that are stored within `myObject` are not in the list of `templateObject` because they where added later then `is` would return false, even if `myObject` has the class `example`

With `myObject.is( '.example' )` you test if the element `myObject` can be found with the selector `.example` (It would not do a full DOM search, it will start at the give element an will - if the selector is more complex - only traverse up through its parents) .  This will always work, but as already mentioned by others if you want to test if the `myObject` has a certain class then you should use `hasClass`

Comment: Would the down voter mind to explain,  what in this information is wrong?